# PHP array_search preg

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

I want to search for '01.' that begins with the number of the array.

Expected output:

```
1 => string '01.02' (length=5)
2 => string '01.03' (length=5)
3 => string '01.04' (length=5)
32 => string '02.02' (length=5)
33 => string '02.03' (length=5)
34 => string '02.04' (length=5)
35 => string '02.05' (length=5)
```

My code:

```
$key = array_search('/^01./', $tomb_datum);
echo $key;
var_dump($key);
```

These preg match not work.

Comment: 1) `array_search` doesn't take a regex as argument. 2) Do you want all elements starting with `01` or just the first one?

Comment: All array number with begin 01.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function dedicated for just this purpose, `preg_grep`. It will take a regular expression as first parameter, and an array as the second.

See the below example: [FIDDLE](https://3v4l.org/9cZUP)

```
$haystack = array (
  '01.02',
  '01.03',
  '02.05',
  '02.07'
);

$matches  = preg_grep ('/^01/i', $haystack);

print_r ($matches);
```

Comment: There is another array, I want to be filtered based on the number next to the date

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to filter the array, use array_filter:

```
$resultArray = array_filter($array, function($elm) {
  if (preg_match('/^01/', $elm)) {
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could just return the `preg_match` directly w/o the `if`s. Also, `preg_grep` is clearly better suited for this...

Comment: There is another array, I want to be filtered based on the number next to the date

Comment: Your approach can be interesting if you avoid the regex: `function($elm) { return strpos($elm, '01') === 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com) which allows for all sorts of array filters:

```
pattern('^01.')->forArray($tomb_datum)->filter()
```

You can also use other methods like:

- `filter()` - for regular (sequential) arrays
- `filterAssoc()` - for associative arrays (`filterAssoc()` preserves keys)
- `filterByKeys()` - to filter an array by keys, not values

PS: Notice that with [T-Regx](https://t-regx) you don't need `/.?/` delimiters!